# how to use ldapsearch for sort attributes filter

Tags: ldap

I would like to know how to use `ldapsearch` filter for sort mail by `gid` number. I tried several command and I don't get what I expected. I got all the entry without sorting or nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-S` parameter (in your case, `-S gid`) in ldapsearch command. From the ldapsearch man page:

> -S attribute
>       Sort the entries returned based on attribute. The default is not to sort entries returned. If attribute is a zero-length string (""),
>   the entries are sorted by the components of their Distinguished Name.
>   See ldap_sort(3) for more details. Note that ldapsearch normally
>   prints out entries as it receives them. The use of the -S option
>   defeats this behavior, causing all entries to be retrieved, then
>   sorted, then printed.